# 単色では無い画素値の範囲指定が出来ない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, 画像処理

#### 前提・実現したいこと

初めて質問します。初心者なので大変初歩的な質問ですがよろしくお願いいたします。Google Colabで画像処理を行っています。そこで画像の色を変更するプログラムを作成しています。そこで画素値（0,255,0）といった他の色が混ざっていない単色であれば色変更が可能なのですが、私が扱っている画像は例えばBGRのBが100～105といった1つの値だけでは表現できない色となっております。画像中の色は黒線で区切られており、その区切りごとに色を変更したいと考えています。イメージ的には山の標高（例えば100ｍごと）ごとに色が区切られているものを、こちらが任意でその色を並び替えるというイメージです。私としては単色では無い画素値を、例えばBGR形式で（100～105,0,150)という様な形で表現して、その画素値を変更したいと考えております。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

先述の様に画素値（0,255,0）といった他の色が混ざっていない単色であれば色変更が可能なのですが、私が扱っている画像は例えばBGRのBが100～105といった1つの値だけでは表現できない色となっております。なので画像の色を変更する事が出来ません。エラーメッセージは次の通りです。エラーメッセージが出ている所は後述するソースコードの7行目です。

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import sys,cv2
import numpy as np

args = sys.argv
img = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")

cond_p = (145　<= img[..., 0] <= 150) & (145 <= img[..., 1] <= 150) & (145 <= img[..., 2] <= 150)
cond_f = np.logical_not(cond_p)
img[cond_p] = [0, 255, 0]
img[cond_f] = [255, 0, 0]

cv2.imwrite("a.jpg", img)
```

#### 試したこと

上記のソースコードにおいて7行目で変更したい画素値を指定します。上の例であれば(145~150,145~150,145~150)の色となっております。インターネットで調査した結果、「Python　以上　以下」と調べて3.のソースコードの様に＜＝を使って表現すると書いていましたが、エラーメッセージが出て上手くいきませんでした。ダメもとで145~155、145～155、145-155の3通りを試しました。しかし2つ目の例では全角が含まれるのでエラーになり、その他の例でも上手くいきませんでした。
*追加情報
⓵print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)
を実行すると
「JPEG (256, 256) L」と出力されます。
⓶print(img.shape)
を実行するとエラーメッセージが次の様に出ます。
「'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'」
尚画像は存在する筈なのですが・・・

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

言語：Python
環境：Windows10
ブラウザ：Google Chrome（Google Colaboratory)
＊ノートパソコンです。全て最新バージョンです。プログラミング中はcolab以外のタブ、アプリは開いていません。

Comment: [numpy.ma.masked_inside: NumPy v1.21 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_inside.html) を使う方法もあります。`cond_p = np.all(np.ma.masked_inside(img, 145, 150).mask, axis=-1)`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。しかし、「'>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'」とエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。どの様にすればよろしいでしょうか。@metropolis

Comment: そのエラーメッセージが表示されるということは、`img` の要素に `None` が含まれているということになります。`sample.jpg` はJPEG ファイルなのでしょうか？

Comment: jpegファイルです。

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'と表示されます。画像は確かに存在するのですが・・・

Comment: `cv2.imread` が `None` を返しているという事は `sample.jpg` が見つからないということですので、ファイルパスを間違えているのではないでしょうか。実際に Google Colab. で試してみたのですが、パスは `/content/sample.jpg` になっています。具体的な確認方法ですが、右側に表示される「ファイル」アイコンをクリックして `sample.jpg` を右クリックするとメニューが表示されますので、その中の「パスをコピー」を選ぶと `sample.jpg` の絶対パスがクリップボードにコピーされます。

Comment: グレースケール JPEGのようだけど, cv2で対応できない？フォーマットのようです (中身が壊れてるとか？)。別ファイルで試すか, あるいは Pillowで読み込む, でしょうね。(Pillowなら, 読み込み後に, `img = np.array(im.convert('RGB'))` で(グレースケールであれば)同様の状態になる)

Comment: @ metropolis：貴方のおっしゃる通りパスが間違っておりました。貴方のお陰で解決出来ました。ありがとうございました。@ oriri：前述の通りパスを間違えただけという初歩的なミスでした。しかしpillowで読み込むという方法は今後も活かしていけそうだなと感じました。結果的に貴方の回答いただいた通り、複数の比較の連結をしない方法であれば対応できることが分かりました。お二方大変ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したようだけど … Pillowで指定したファイルが正しいファイルなら, グレースケールのはずで, cv2で読み込み時に `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`指定で 2次元として読み込めます (条件判断減らすことが可能)

Comment: 仰る通りこの画像はグレースケール画像です。貴方が仰る通りその方が条件を減らす事が出来て良いですよね。活用します。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

処理の内容が合ってるかどうかわからないけど,
とりあえずエラー出ないようにするには …

まず, NumPyでは(たいてい) N-d Array 単位で演算処理を行うので, `(145　<= img[..., 0] <= 150)` という記述(複数の比較の連結) は受け付けないようです。

質問の条件をそのまま置き換えた形

```py
cond_p = ((145 <= img[..., 0]) & (img[..., 0] <= 150)
        & (145 <= img[..., 1]) & (img[..., 1] <= 150)
        & (145 <= img[..., 2]) & (img[..., 2] <= 150))
```

(追記)
RGB (RGBAではなく) 3つの要素で, 実際に(質問のように)値の範囲がすべて同じなら, 次のようにも可能(なはず)

```py
cond_p = np.all((145 <= img) & (img <= 150), axis=-1)
```

あと注意点として, 何の(何系の)画像処理か不明だけど,
厳密に値の範囲指定する場合, JPEG形式は向いていないかも？
(不可逆圧縮であり, また, 読み込むライブラリーによっては値が異なることも)

---

#### コメント受けての(質問での)エラーの件確認

以下を colabなどで実行すると何が出ますか？
また, `img = cv2.imread(〜)` 後の, `img.shape` を表示した場合何が出ますか？
… 以上を, 質問に追記してみて下さい

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('sample.jpg')
print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。しかし、「'NoneType' object is not subscriptable」とエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。どの様にすればよろしいでしょうか。@oriri

Comment: @黒ちゃん Colaboratoryで処理行ってるなら, 一番ありがちなのはファイルが存在しないとかでしょうか。`img = cv2.imread("sample.jpg"); if img: print('完了')` みたいな判断行うとよいかも

Comment: コメント受けての(質問での)エラーの件確認を拝見しました。ご提示いただいたコードを実行するとJPEG (256, 256) Lと出力されます。しかしimg.shapeでは'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'とエラーメッセージが出ます。私もファイルが無いのではと確認しましたが、確かに存在するようなのです。if img: print('完了')の様な判断をするとエラーメッセージは出ませんでしたが、出力はされませんでしたね。